# Drag accepted operation not observed

Tags: uwp, drag-and-drop

I have this `DragOver` handler, practically out of the book:

```
  e.DragUIOverride.Caption = "my text";
  var op = DataPackageOperation.None;

  if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems)) {
    var items = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
    if (items.Any()) {
      var file = items.First() as StorageFile;
      op = (file?.FileType == ".myext") ? DataPackageOperation.Copy : DataPackageOperation.None;
    }
  }

  System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(op);
  e.AcceptedOperation = op;
```

The reason for `op` is to avoid setting the `AcceptedOperation` twice (not normally required in samples but one of my desperate attempts). The trace at the end shows that this code sets the exact operation I need, no chance of failure. Yet, when running, all I get is a No Entry sign denoting a denied drag operation.

W10 20H2, for what it's worth.

Comment: May I know what is the value of `op`? Is it `DataPackageOperation.None`? If the value is `None`, then it is expected to see the No Entry sign as `DataPackageOperation.None` means no action will be taken. It's the default icon for `DataPackageOperation.None`.

Comment: None or Copy, depending on whether the file matches the extension or not. That's my problem. The value passed is OK, still I don't see the diference in either the icon or in the actual operation.

Comment: Could you please share an [mcve] on Githu or OneDrive? I could not reproduce your issue with the code you posted.

Comment: What I discovered in the meantime is that if the DragOver handler is synchronous code, it works. If it's async because I need to call `await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync()`, it no longer works. Also, if I ever try to assing `e.DragUIOverride.Caption` in such an async handler, I get a COM failed exception.

Comment: It will be better if you could share a sample on Github or OneDrive so that I could debug the code directly.

Comment: Could you add a language tag to this question?

Comment: Why do you think the language is particularly important? The question was about UWP functionality, it doesn't make any difference what language you compile it from.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: By not trying to adapt to the file type. As soon as I try to get the file type, it fails because `e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync()` is async.